# Wordpress Custom Menu Images and Style

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to modify a theme to fit my design in Wordpress. I'm having a lot of trouble editing the menu bar in any way (apart from just colors).

I need to know how to achieve something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGiVB.png

Is it possible to just add the image to the menu bar and link certain areas? How can I get this into my website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to crop image with whole black color without text portion and apply as background image to menu's "ul" tag. and then to display that text links you have to play with padding & margin.

thanks